# How do I pass arguments to an IIFE in vue from vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

We have two scripts that are loaded into the head tag upon launch. One of these scripts points to an IIFE in a local .js file. This is third party software.

```
/*
Inline configuration
*********************
Object is now being instantiated against the OOo object (1 global class)
To call this object, place the below in the click event
OOo.oo_launch(event, 'oo_feedback1')
*/
(function (w, o) {
  'use strict'

  var OpinionLabInit = function () {
    // for SPA deployment, o.inlineFeedShow would be the function we tell clients to add to the onclick event of their inline link
    o.inlineFeedbackShow = function (event) {
      var replacePattern = '://' + window.location.host
      if (window.location.host !== 'src.companyX.com' && window.location.host !== 'checkout.companyX.com') {
        replacePattern = '://test.checkout.companyX.com'
      }
      o.oo_feedback = new o.Ocode({
        referrerRewrite: {
          searchPattern: /:\/\/[^/]*/,
          replacePattern: replacePattern
        },
        customVariables: {
          flow: '',
          clientId: '',
          srcCorrelationId: '',
          visitorId: '',
          sAccount: ''
        }
      })

      // Now that oo_feedback has been re-initialized with the custom variable and contextual of the current page, launch the comment card
      o.oo_launch(event, 'oo_feedback')
    }
    o.oo_launch = function (e, feedback) {
      var evt = e || window.event
      o[feedback].show(evt)
    }
    if (typeof OOo !== 'undefined' && typeof OOo.releaseDetails !== 'object') {
      OOo.releaseDetails = []
    }
    OOo.releaseDetails.push({
      author: 'DN',
      timeStamp: '07/26/2019, 10:56:32',
      fileName: 'oo_conf_inline.js',
      fileVersion: '1.0',
      ticketNumber: 'DYN-1042506',
      gitDiff: 'N/A'
    })
  };

  OpinionLabInit()

})(window, OOo)
```

What I want to do is pass a few state object properties from the Vuex store to be the values in the 'customVariables' object.

For example:
I want to use from store/modules/user.js

```
state = {
  flow.NEW_USER
}
```

and have in the customVariables object

```
customVariables: {
          flow: flow.NEW_USER,
          clientId: '',
          srcCorrelationId: '',
          visitorId: '',
          sAccount: ''
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the third party code?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `state` variable is globally available in all adjacent `.js` files. If so you could modify the **IIFE** to inject a third argument, which would be your `state` variable.

I think that your object notation of the `state` variable should be like this.

```
state = {
  flow: flow.NEW_USER
}
```

Give the **IIFE** a third parameter called `s` (or whatever you prefer).

```
(function (w, o, s) {
  'use strict'

      ...

      o.oo_feedback = new o.Ocode({
        referrerRewrite: {
          searchPattern: /:\/\/[^/]*/,
          replacePattern: replacePattern
        },
        customVariables: {
          flow: s.flow, // flow.NEW_USER is now here
          clientId: '',
          srcCorrelationId: '',
          visitorId: '',
          sAccount: ''
        }
      })

     ...

})(window, OOo, state)
```

And inject the `state` variable here at the bottom.

Now this only works if you have global access to your `state` variable. And it has to be defined *before* the **IIFE** is executed.